# Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceReference1.EmployeeModel' to type 'System.IConvertible'.In order to avoid that error,What can v do?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services

Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceReference1.EmployeeModel' to type 'System.IConvertible'.
What is exactly above error and in order to avoid it wht we have to do?

```
protected void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  JavaScriptSerializer jsn = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("localhost:50506/Service1.svc/CreateEmployee";); 
  request.Method = "POST"; 
  request.ContentLength = 10; 

  EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel(); //i added emp fields in to emp 
  Byte[] data = { Convert.ToByte(emp) }; 

  Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
  requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //in Byte[] data line the error is coming
}
```

Comment: Welcome - please use the edit link instead of the comments to add new info to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code is failing when it is trying to convert the employee object to a byte array because the employee class does not implement the IConvertible Interface.

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but because you have declared the JavaScriptSerializer, it looks like you may want to return json.  You might be looking for this then:

```
 void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
     JavaScriptSerializer jsn = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
     WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("localhost:50506/Service1.svc/CreateEmployee";); 
     request.Method = "POST"; 
     request.ContentLength = 10;  
     EmployeeModel emp = new EmployeeModel(); 

     string data = jsn.Serialize(emp);
     Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); 
     requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); 
  }
```